# android device always shows offline until restarted

Tags: android

Whenever I connect my android device to PC via USB it always shows offline and I am left with only one option to restart the device then only it shows online and sometime's when USB cable is slightly disturbed even that turns the device offline, anyone here could tell a solution.

Comment: Try changing USB cable.

Comment: That's the best solution, change your USB cable.

Comment: but my usb works fine when using for anyother purpose other then development

Answer (score 0):

Sometime I am also facing this problem 
Go to Setting > Display > Sleep 
and then select "Never Sleep".
It may help you.